# Windows 2003 to log on no matter how it turned off

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have a windows server 2003, which I use Teamviewer to connect to. When there is a power failure, and the computer restarts, it will not load Teamviewer. It gets stuck on a screen which asks why the computer was turned off. There is no keyboard or mouse connected to the server and I need Teamviewer to open every time. I don't want the screen asking why it was turned off to show up ever. I turned off Shutdown Event Tracker by doing the following:

Open gpedit.msc > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System click Display Shutdown Event Tracker and then selected the disable radio button. Is this enough to prevent that screen to show up again? or is there anything else I need to change?

Comment: That should be the correct thing to change.  Is there some reason why you are relying on a screen sharing tool that requires the system automatically login?  What is wrong with the remote desktop software?

Comment: the computer is connected to a dynamic ip, so Teamviewer would work even if the ip changes

Comment: RDP works fine even if the IP changes, just have the computer update a dynamic DNS service somewhere, create a VPN, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are starting Teamviewer via the startup folder. You should instead be running Teamviewer as a service. Running it as a service would allow you to connect even if the server is not logged in, and you could connect with the shutdown reason window open.

From what I remember, in the options somewhere is a checkbox that says "Start TeamViewer with Windows", but that is from a while ago so I don't know if they have renamed that checkbox.